# Mongodb automatically changing datatype while storing values

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I have following code in asp.net mvc c#

```
   [Display(Name = "Marks Range ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Minimum Marks is Required.")]
    public int? min_marks { get; set; }
```

While storing data from from in mongodb the datatype automatically changes to string ?

Any reason for this strange behaviour or how to correct this ?

Answer (score 0):

Using ScaffoldColumn for prevent from  default datatype :

```
   [Display(Name = "Marks Range ")]
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Minimum Marks is Required.")]
   [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
   public int? min_marks { get; set; }
```

Comment: ScaffoldColumn would hide it in view.I dont want to hide it.